# Range problem when removing background or whitening in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, transparency, background-removal

I have a .BMP picture (110 MB in size) that has a background (white) that I want to remove. I converted my .BMP picture because of it large size to .JPG format to use in Photoshop.

So my main picture is:

[image]

I did some works in Photoshop and whitening background but when I zoom it, the works has Range Problem and informally get low quality (zoom 2 pictures to see different).

My problem is when I removed the background or white it, the quality of work is down and Range Problem occurred. What is the way to do it without getting stuck in mentioned problem?

It's not important that it be black or reflect the exact translucency. I want to just remove the background (gray background in main picture) without the range problem. Is there a way?

[image]

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking but once you get to the bottom image try using a Levels Adjustment Layer and see if that does what you're looking for. I'm really unsure though as there seems to be some language barriers.

Comment: @Ryan it's not important that be black or reflect the exact translucency. I means just remove background (gray background in main picture) and my character didnt get Range problem. is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure the top image is the only layer, so if there's a default white background layer then delete it.

1. Layer → Layer Style → Blending Options
2. Under This Layer at the bottom see how the left part of the white is moved in. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag that part of the slider with your mouse until its to your liking.

[image]

Comment: Could you send me your edited picture on my files?

Comment: @user66044 no, I am here to teach people how to do things, not do it for them

Comment: My problem is via removing background, background and text changed simultaneously.

Comment: @user66044 Hit the **Edit Button your question** to include a new screenshot of where you're stuck and I'll do my best to help you

Comment: I did it please see

Comment: @user66044 you changed the Opacity slider at the top. You need to change the Blend If: Gray, This Layer slider at the bottom (second from bottom). I updated my answer circling what you need to be adjusting.

Comment: I think select with Magic Tool is not appropriate here to avoid character region from range.

Comment: @user66044 see my comment and updated image

Comment: Thanks I get it but please see my updated question. there is some problem. selecting is not good.

Comment: You're going to have to manually fix some of that using a layer mask or eraser tool if you need it more precise. @user66044

Comment: If I want a darker text color, while not renge what to do?

Comment: @user66044 adjust the levels since its a black and white